# retorno de json en php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Buenas amigos de stackoverflow espero que puedan ayudarme con mi problema. Lo siguiente es, estoy programando con mvc y poo en php y quiero utilizar ajax, el problemas es que quiero mostrar el json por consola desde una funcion en php y estoy atascado en esa parte. Partes de mi codigo:

Por parte de la vista archivo js

```
$('#consulta').keyup(function(){
        let consulta = $('#consulta').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../controlador/consulta.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { consulta },
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
    })
```

Parte del controlador archivo php

```
class usuarioController{

        public function consultarDatos($query){
            $c = new conectar();
            $conexion = $c->conexion();
            $result = pg_query($conexion,$query);

            $json = array();
            while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){
                $json[] = array(
                    'personal_id' => $row['personal_id'],
                    'primer_nom' => $row['primer_nom'],
                    'segundo_nom' => $row['segundo_nom'],
                    'primer_ape' => $row['primer_ape'],
                    'segundo_ape' => $row['segundo_ape'],
                    'cedula' => $row['cedula'],
                    'correo' => $row['correo']
                );
            }
            $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
            return $jsonstring;
        }
    }
```

Parte del controlador archivo consulta.php donde quiero mostrar el json por consola

```
 <?php

        include "../modelo/conexion.php";
        include "usuarioController.php";

        $consulta = $_POST['consulta'];
        $datos = array(
            $consulta
        );

        $obj = new usuarioController();
        if(!empty($consulta)){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE primer_nom LIKE '$datos[0]%'";
            $objeto = $obj->consultarDatos($query); 
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: En tu controlador modifica tu var $json = array(); por $json = array[]; Ya que vas a ingresar indices, no necesitas la función array sino declararla únicamente con indice vació o 0. prueba!

Comment: ¿Que problema te encuentras? ¿Lanza algún error? ¿El resultado no es el esperado?

Comment: ¿En qué momento haces la salida del JSON?